# Maven dependency for java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/streaming/util/Clock

Tags: maven, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I tried a lot but still not able to see the maven dependency for 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/streaming/util/Clock

Could somebody please let me know the best way to find the dependency if we have some good practice. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the dependency I was looking for:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: 2.10-1.1.0 isn't the latest but [2.11-1.3.1](http://search.maven.org/#search|gav|1|g%3A%22org.apache.spark%22%20AND%20a%3A%22spark-streaming_2.11%22).