# spark-nlp : DocumentAssembler initializing failing with java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/ml/util/MLWritable$class ESG

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, johnsnowlabs-spark-nlp

I'm trying to use the [john snow ESG model](https://nlp.johnsnowlabs.com/2022/09/06/finclf_augmented_esg_en.html).

And I keep getting the following error:

Line `document_assembler = DocumentAssembler().setInputCol('text').setOutputCol('document')`

Error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/ml/util/MLWritable$class`

```py
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.DocumentAssembler.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/ml/util/MLWritable$class
    at com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.DocumentAssembler.<init>(DocumentAssembler.scala:16)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:397)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:257)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:195)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:115)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.ml.util.MLWritable$class
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:419)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ClassLoaders$LibraryClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.scala:151)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:352)
    ... 13 more
```

I'm working over Databricks, with the following clusters:

- Cluster 1:

  - Runtime: 13.2 ML (includes Apache Spark 3.4.0, GPU, Scala 2.12)
  - Worker & Driver type: Standard_NC21s_v3    224 GB Memory, 2 GPUs
- Cluster 2:

  - Runtime: 12.2 LTS ML (includes Apache Spark 3.3.2, Scala 2.12)
  - Node type: Standard_DS5_v2   56 GB Memory, 16 Cores

Added libraries to the cluster are according to [here](https://www.johnsnowlabs.com/setup-spark-nlp-on-databricks-in-2-minutes-and-get-the-taste-of-scalable-nlp/):

- PyPi: spark-nlp (tried with and without version)
- PyPi: pyspark (tried with and without version)
- Maven: com.johnsnowlabs.nlp:spark-nlp_2.11:2.5.0

Spark NLP Version: 5.2.2

Spark Version: 3.4.0 (Tried also with 14.1 Cluster with 3.5.0 version)

Code:

```py
import sparknlp

spark = sparknlp.start()

sparknlp.version(), spark.version

from sparknlp.base import *
from sparknlp.annotator import *
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
import pandas as pd

document_assembler = DocumentAssembler().setInputCol('text').setOutputCol('document')
```

---

I found the following questions and data online but haven't manage to get a solution:

1. [spark-nlp : DocumentAssembler initializing failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63398148/spark-nlp-documentassembler-initializing-failing-with-java-lang-noclassdeffou)
2. [Maven dependency for java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30664457/maven-dependency-for-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-spark-streaming)
3. [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34236112/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-spark-sparkconf)
4. [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError](https://community.databricks.com/t5/data-engineering/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-spark-internal-logging/td-p/12079)
5. [NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/ml/util/MLWritable](https://lightrun.com/answers/databricks-spark-deep-learning-noclassdeffounderror-orgapachesparkmlutilmlwritable)
6. [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/ml/util/MLWritable$class](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/96006)
7. [NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/ml/util/MLWritable](https://github.com/databricks/spark-deep-learning/issues/194)
8. [TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable - DocumentAssembler() - Spark NLP](https://community.databricks.com/t5/data-engineering/typeerror-javapackage-object-is-not-callable-documentassembler/td-p/20711)
9. [Natural language processing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/machine-learning/reference-solutions/natural-language-processing)
10. [apache-spark-support](https://github.com/JohnSnowLabs/spark-nlp#apache-spark-support)